# I am trying to run terraform init but getting this error: Failed to query available provider packages

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp

Terraform init is giving the following error. No version has been upgraded and it was working few days back but suddenly it is failing.

```
Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws:
could not connect to registry.terraform.io: Failed to request discovery
document: Get "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": read: connection reset by peer


when I run curl from the server, it is not able to connect as well. 
 curl https://registry.terraform.io/
 curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to registry.terraform.io:443
```

Comment: Could be some MitM. Is https://registry.terraform.io/ opens properly in your browser? 

Or you can check the certificate using https://serverfault.com/a/749381/494513

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a network where an admin might have installed a proxy between you and the internet? If so, you need to get the signing certificates and configure them in your provider.

If you're on a home network or a public one, this is a man in the middle attack. Do not use this network.

If you have the certificates, they can be configured in your aws provider by pointing `cacert_path`, `cert_path` and `key_path` at the appropriate `.pem` files.

If you have verified that there is a valid reason to have a proxy between you and the internet, you are not touching production, and the certificates are hard to come by, you can test your code by setting `insecure = true` on your provider. Obviously, don't check that in.

Answer (score 1):

**How I fix that nre relic provider downloading issue**

Error while installing newrelic/newrelic v3.13.0: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/newrelic/newrelic: failed to retrieve authentication checksums for provider: the request failed
│ after 2 attempts, please try again later: Get "https://github.com/newrelic/terraform-provider-newrelic/releases/download/v3.13.0/terraform-provider-newrelic_3.13.0_SHA256SUMS": net/http: request canceled
│ while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

https://learnubuntu.com/change-dns-server/
add google nameservers here:
/etc/resolv.conf
[image]
and then check with thsi command:
dig google.com | grep SERVER
and done.
This is a temp change, will disappear when moving to the new terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue was in the bug with ipv6

Disabling ipv6 helped me

Answer (score 0):

I get this error from time to time. It's been frequently reported on the terrafrom github page. One particular comment always reminds me to refresh my network settings (e.g. restart network connection):

> OK, I think I have isolated and resolved the issue in my case. It's
> always DNS to blame in the end, right? I hardcoded CloudFlare DNS
> (1.1.1.1 and its IPv4 and IPv6 aliases) into my network settings on
> the laptop, and since then everything seems to be working like a
> treat.